# Can I obtain fingerprint value?

Tags: android, fingerprint

I try to get the fingerprint value and store it. After that, I try to compare that

value with the value of fingerprint that comes from another hardware, fingerprint

sensor.

Q1. Is it possible to compare between them?

Q2. If it is possible, how can I obtain that value?

I've searched about those questions and I found that it is impossible. But I think

that the way to get fingerprint information exists. I want a clear answer. Sorry

for not uploading any codes and I've searched as far as I can.

Comment: No it is not possible. (For security and privacy reasons of course)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you recommend another alternatives to handle this situation?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is available at http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint

Answer (score 1):

> But I think that the way to get fingerprint information exists

You are welcome to use some sort of external fingerprint scanner, one that has an API that provides you with the fingerprint data.

Otherwise, at least for devices that are part of the Google Play ecosystem, fingerprint data is not available to anything. For example, see [the Android 8.1 Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.1/android-8.1-cdd#7_3_sensors), specifically:

> [C-1-7] MUST have all identifiable fingerprint data encrypted and cryptographically authenticated such that **they cannot be acquired, read or altered outside of the Trusted Execution Environment (TEE)** as documented in the implementation guidelines on the Android Open Source Project site.

(emphasis added)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Again, Can you recommend another alternatives to handle this situations? I've read about SHA1 hash value and in that post, as I understood, I can get that hash value. What about using that value to compare?

Comment: @NaJunYeop: What are these hashes you speak of? In any case, that sounds like something that would go against the fingerprint HAL implementation guidelines: _"Raw fingerprint data **or derivatives** (e.g. templates) must never be accessible from outside the sensor driver or TEE."_

Comment: @NaJunYeop: "I've read about SHA1 hash value and in that post, as I understood, I can get that hash value" -- there is nothing in [the Android 8.1 CDD](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.1/android-8.1-cdd) that refers to a SHA1 of a fingerprint. "What about using that value to compare?" -- since it does not exist, you cannot use it. "Can you recommend another alternatives to handle this situations?" -- build your own hardware and OS, I guess.

Comment: Finally I decided to solve in different way. Thanks for your kindness! :)